# How did Stane's guards gain control of the Ten Rings soldiers?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man

In the movie, in one scene we see Obadiah Stane arriving at Ten Rings HQ, while he and the Rings' leader are inside Stane uses some device to neutralize the leader after he realizes his plans went wrong.

The next scene shows Stane coming out the hut and his mercenaries gathered around all of the Ten Rings soldiers.

How did Stane's guards round up the Ten Rings troops? They didn't appear to have any weapons when they arrived, and the troopss appeared to outnumber them.

Comment: Considering that Stane used the small, easily-concealed paralysis device, it's safe to assume that his soldiersmay have the similar devices,which they could use to simply apply temporary paralyze to rings soldiers.

Answer (score 2):

The real answer is - **WE DON'T KNOW**

But, there are several possibilities:

1. A group of highly trained men is usually capable of overtaking a group of less trained men
2. The above is especially true if the attackers have "the element of surprise" and a **technological advantage** that the other side is not prepared for.

Now remember, these are the personal bodyguards of Obadiah Stane, effectively one of the key figures of the biggest weapons dealer in the world: Stark Industries. Consider what Stane himself does with a little bit of tech to the leader of the terrorists. More importantly, remember how Tony Stark defeats a whole camp full of terrorists with some simple armor and a flamethrower.